# Integral scheme and variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In chapter 2 of this [note](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf), the author defined variety as separated scheme of finite type over Spec$(k)$ for any field. But in Hartshorn there is still an *integral*.

I presume that he wants the variety to be able to be non-irreducible, i.e., the alegraic set. But integral is equivalent to irreducible and reduced. Does it hurt anything if we removed the reducedness?

Also, what does *separated* refer to? If we say separated scheme, then it is separated over Spec$(\mathbb{Z})$. However, i have seen another [definition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/020C) saying that it is separted over Spec$(k)$. Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. If you remove the reducedness you will in general have nilpotency in your structure sheaf. The notion of a variety varies a lot in the literature depending on what the author wants to do.

A morphism $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ between two schemes is separated if the diagonal $\Delta_X \subset X \times_Y X$ is closed. If you take $Y = \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, then the fibre product will be the regular product and you will get your definition of a separated scheme back. Now you can also take $Y =\text{Spec}(k)$ and think about that situation.